# Finding a float in a list by index method with rounding error(Python)

Tags: python, indexing, rounding-error

So often , the value we got are affected by rounding errors, when we operate on floats numbers e.g. 1.000000000001, if I want to find a value like 1.0 in the list, what's the cleanest way of doing it? 
I was trying to find the index of 1.0, and so to find the corresponding y value in y list.I have thought about using a if statement, to find x value within a certain range, such as 1.0+/-0.0000000000001, I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. Thanks for everyone.

```
xlist=[0,1.0000000000001,2.0.3.0]
ylist=[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]
def numberfinder(xlist=[],ylist=[]):
    return ylist[xlist.index(1.0)]

print numberfinder(xlist,ylist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should round both lists first as given below:

```
xlist=[round(i,1) for i in xlist]
ylist=[round(i,1) for i in ylist]
```

Now xlist will become:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

and 1.0 can be found.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists have same len one way is using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a dictionary :

```
xlist=[0,1.0000000000001,2.0.3.0]
ylist=[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]
>>> zip_list=zip(xlist,ylist)
>>> d_list=dict(zip_list)
>>> d_list[1.0]
1.0000000000001
```